# Entries in the reference section not appearing in the order I have cited

Tags: bibliographies, koma-script

I am using a template which uses `\usepackage{bibgerm}` for citing the references. I have included the references in the `.bib` file and as well cited them in the following order:

1. L. M. , Turbulence in Fluids. Kluwer Academic Publishers, 1997.
2. J. Decaix, G. Balarac, M. Dreyer, M. Farhat, and C. Münch. RANS and LES computations of the tip-leakage vortex for different gap widths. Journal of Turbulence, 16(4):309–341, 2015.
3. J. Jeong and F. Hussain. Hussain, f.: On the identification of a vortex. jfm 285, 69-94. Journal of Fluid Mechanics, 285:69 – 94, 02 1995.
4. H. K. Moffatt and A. Tsinober. Helicity in laminar and turbulent flow. Annual Review of Fluid
   Mechanics, 24(1):281–312, 1992.

But in the reference section, the citations are printed in the following order:

1. J. Decaix, G. Balarac, M. Dreyer, M. Farhat, and C. Münch. RANS and LES computations of the tip-leakage vortex for different gap widths. Journal of Turbulence, 16(4):309–341, 2015.
2. J. Jeong and F. Hussain. Hussain, f.: On the identification of a vortex. jfm 285, 69-94. Journal of Fluid Mechanics, 285:69 – 94, 02 1995.
3. L. M. , Turbulence in Fluids. Kluwer Academic Publishers, 1997.
4. H. K. Moffatt and A. Tsinober. Helicity in laminar and turbulent flow. Annual Review of Fluid Mechanics, 24(1):281–312, 1992.

as you can see the entries references are not printed in the order I have included and cited. I am using ShareLatex (Overleaf) for writing this document. The template I am using is based on Koma-Script 'report' class. Can someone please tell why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: Which bibliography style does your document employ? This piece of information may be contained in `bibgerm.sty`. By the way, I've heard of the `germbib` package, but never before of the `bibgerm` package. Is it available online somewhere?

Comment: It is using this `\bibliographystyle{abbrv}`. The reference section looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGsTX.jpg). Regarding the package, the template is provided by my University. So I don't know about that package.

Comment: Indeed, the `abbrv` bibliography style is programmed to sort the entries alphabetically by  authors' surnames. Can you edit the style file and change `\bibliographystyle{abbrv}` to `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`? After making that change, you'll have to run a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Comment: If the university gave you the template they perhaps want the alphabetic sorting. Ask before trying to change this.

Comment: I never heard of "L. M. Turbulence". He or she must have been very accomplished to have such a broad phenomenon named after him/her. :-)

Comment: @DonaldArseneau That is Marcel Lesieur, apparently universally known (within fluid mechanics). Sort of like DEK, I presume :)